# replacing specific strings in a SELECT sql query (PLUS) if contains LIKE '%text%' replace the whole result

Tags: php, mysql

Replacing strings in a select query to kill off bad characters that will be harmful to folder names I am creating.  That part is working well.

```
SELECT cust_name = 
REPLACE(REPLACE([cust_name],'.',''),'/','-')
FROM work,dbo.cust cust_name
WHERE work.cust_id_bill_to = cust_name.cust_code AND
work.job_id = '44514' AND
work.sub_job_id = '11'
```

(THAT) Works great.  BUT NOW I have one customer result who has hundreds of duplicate customer names based on stores and franchises, need only 1 customer name returned.  So, have to figure out how to add code that would replace the entire result where this string is used.. mcdonald

So if the result comes back with `MCDONALDS STORE#4567` I need to replace that with simply `MCDONALDS`.

```
WHERE cust_name LIKE N %mcdonald%
```

No matter the full text result in this case, like an if statement combined with my replace statement and a wildcard to boot?  Changes the hundreds of those results to a single answer ... if it has mcdonald in it, it just gives me MCDONALDS as a result.  Any ideas how to put that together. TIA. JP

Comment: `if (cust_name like '%mcdonald%', 'mcdondald', cust_Name)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CHARINDEX` to find a string within another string. If the result is 0, then the string is not found.

Then you could combine that with a `CASE` statement.

```
select 
    case when charindex('mcdonalds', cust_name) = 0
        then replace(replace([cust_name],'.',''),'/','-')
        else 'mcdonalds'
    end as customer name
from ...
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver, Its not about the case, the case is fine.  Its about getting every result containing "mcdonald", so %mcdonald% and replace that with simply "mcdonalds" without changing the existing function that is now working.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, (1) I am querying job records to get a customer name, create a folder from that.  So, naturally having a . or a / in a folder name is bad.  So, I am replacing that.  Its all working well.

Comment: (2) one customer turns out to be a franchise with hundreds of different long variations of their company name in the database.  MCDONALD STORE 1234, etc.  For Those I need to simply replace the whole string which varies with a single result to create its one common folder. simply MCDONALDS.

Comment: MCDONALDS 123, MCDONALDS STORE 5678, STORE 1234 MCDONALD's all return simple MCDONALDS.

Comment: That is what my answer will give you. If the cust_name has mcdonalds in it, then just return 'mcdonalds', if not return the cleaned up string based on your text replace logic.

Comment: YES, you are correct.  I'm not sure why my code wasn't doing it and I kept tweaking on it and massaging it and BAM!  So, thanks so much it was a very quick correct answer but took me awhile to make it work here.  Merry Christmas!